# Synonym for public

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I am currently stuck with the following situation. Imagine that there is a website which offers premium content that only paying members can access. However, there are a few pages which is available for everyone. Which word can be used to describe those public available pages?

Problem is, that I cannot use „public“ because this word is an identifier in the programming language I am using.

Comment: What does the programming language have to do with what you call it? You can call it "Freddie" in your programs and still display "Public"

Comment: It's not about displaying it.

Comment: That pricing model is sometimes referred to as "freemium", where some content is free and available to anyone, but premium content is available only to paid subscribers.

Comment: Off topic (request for advice on naming variables).

Comment: Just to clarify: This is **not** a request for naming of *variables*. This is not off-topic either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Open/free/general/unpaid/complimentary* pick one that best suits your need.

Answer (score 3):

Since the content is not subject to a premium, perhaps you could use *freely available* instead.

Answer (score 2):

Community, free, open, unrestricted